# Problem with code:parse error on input `<-'

Tags: haskell

Today I have a new problem with another code in Haskell: I get the following error "parse error on input `<-'". Would someone explain to me what is wrong with the code and how to make it right? Thanks!

````
f :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
f (h, w) (a, b) k l =  let x <- [1..w]
                           y <- [1..h]              
                           zahl1 <- [1..k]
                           zahl2 <- [1..l]
                       in [if ((y, x) == (a, b)) then zahl1 else zahl2]  ```
````

Comment: I think you're looking for `do`, not `let...in`

Comment: `let` uses `=`, not `<-`.

Answer (score 1):

The left arrow (`<-`) is used to assign values inside `do` notation, like this:

```hs
main = do
  line <- getLine
  print line
```

The equals sign is used to assign values as part of a `let ... in ...` expression, like this:

```hs
main =
  let line = "hello"
  in print line
```

So mechanically you might think to replace `<-` with `=`, but that wouldn't work for your case. It looks like you're trying to create a list using a list comprehension, but instead you're creating a list with only one value in it. I think this may be what you're trying to do:

```hs
f :: ( Int, Int ) -> ( Int, Int ) -> Int -> Int -> [ [ Int ] ]                 
f ( h, w ) ( a, b ) k l =
  let
    zahl1 = [ 1 .. k ]
    zahl2 = [ 1 .. l ]
  in
    [ if ( y, x ) == ( a, b ) then zahl1 else zahl2
    | x <- [ 1 .. w ]
    , y <- [ 1 .. h ]
    ]
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, but as a bit of trivia you can write list comprehensions using `do` notation:

```hs
f ( h, w ) ( a, b ) k l = do
  x <- [ 1 .. w ]
  y <- [ 1 .. h ]
  if ( y, x ) == ( a, b )
    then [ 1 .. k ]
    else [ 1 .. l ]
```

Comment: ok, I think I understand what you mean. I tried to run the code again and this time I got and the error "Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int' " for k and l. Does it show it because they are in a list?

Comment: The first version with the list comprehension apparently requires a type signature to compile. I edited my answer to add that.